# Airflow is not loading my configuration file

Tags: airflow, airflow-api

Hi I'm trying to test out the airflow API, and for that I'm trying to change the default configuration

```
[api]
auth_backend = airflow.api.auth.backend.deny_all
```

As guided at https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/api.html#api-authentication

To test out the API calls y I'm trying to set the **airflow.api.auth_backend** to default, ej

```
[api]
auth_backend = airflow.api.auth.backend.default
```

But when I run my airflow docker, and enter to the airflow webserver container, I see that my changes are there on the configuration file. I see my file at **/opt/airflow/airflow.cfg** with my changes but when I run the command

```
airflow config get-value api auth_backend
```

or

```
airflow config list
```

I don't see this changes!!! As if they were not loaded.

I checked the environment and my airflow home is correct **AIRFLOW_HOME=/opt/airflow**

Answer (score 3):

This is my second time I ran to this problem and I swear is the last one. There is a variable on the configuration file **unit-test-mode** that overwrites the configuration file. This is clearly indicated on the Configuration Reference docs at:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#unit-test-mode

> unit_test_mode
> **Turn unit test mode on (overwrites many configuration options with test values at runtime)**

Check out that this variable is set to False

```
[core]
unit_test_mode = False
```

Comment: Haha good to see you found the answer! Kuddos that you shared it :)